# Error al loguear php en mvc

Tags: php, mysql, login

Buenas noches a todos,después de buscar y buscar(son muy de pegarme mucho con el código y mirar cosas antes de pedir ayuda),recurro a mi primer post en esta pagina,porque es algo que me esta trayendo de cabeza.

Estoy en el ultimo año del CFGS de DAW,y estamos con una app de login y registro con MVC,para "juguetear" con el patron de diseño,me funciona todo perfecto:registro,eliminar,actualizar...,pero,a la hora del logueo...hay algo que me esta fallando,y lo he intentado de mil maneras,no se porque,no me saca el usuario que quiero consultar(el que inicia sesion).

**UsuariosController.php**

```
public function loguear(){

        $usuario = new Usuario();

            $idUsuario = $_POST['idUsuario']; //es el correo electronico
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];

            $usuario->setIdUsuario($idUsuario); //seteo el idUsuario
            $usuarioQueSolicitaLoguearse = $usuario->getIdUsuario(); //lo recojo
            $usuarioEnBaseDeDatos = $usuario->loguearUsuario($usuarioQueSolicitaLoguearse); //consulto a la base de datos el idUsuario introducido por el usuario

                if($usuarioQueSolicitaLoguearse == $usuarioEnBaseDeDatos){

                        echo "TODO OK!!!!!<br>";
                        echo "USUARIO SOLICITANTE: " .$usuarioQueSolicitaLoguearse."<br>";
                        echo "USUARIO EXISTENTE BBDD: " .$usuarioEnBaseDeDatos."<br>";  
                    // session_start();
                    // $_SESSION['usuarioLogueado'] = $usuarioQueSolicitaLoguearse;

                    //  echo $_SESSION['usuarioLogueado'];  
                    // redireccciono al controlador y el metodo logueo
                    // $this->redirect("Usuarios","logueo");
                    // $this->redirectWithSession("Usuarios","logueo",$_SESSION['usuarioLogueado']);
                }else{
                        var_dump($usuarioEnBaseDeDatos);
                        echo "<br>";
                        var_dump($usuarioQueSolicitaLoguearse);
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "USUARIO NO ENCONTRADO<br>";
                        echo "USUARIO SOLICITANTE: " .$usuarioQueSolicitaLoguearse."<br>";
                        echo "USUARIO EXISTENTE BBDD: ".$usuarioEnBaseDeDatos."<br>";   
                        //redireccciono al controlador y el metodo logueoNotFound
                        // $this->redirect("Usuarios","logueoNotFound");
                }
    }
```

**Usuarios.php**

```
public function loguearUsuario($idUsuario){

        $query = "SELECT idUsuario FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario = ".$idUsuario;

        $resultado = $this->db()->query($query);

        return $resultado;


    }
```

En el navegador,el resultado de la busqueda en la bbdd me sale false(resultado del var_dump de UsuariosController.php),y como consecuencia,el echo vacío,con lo cual,lógico que no haga la comparativa del if.

**Vista en el navegador**

> bool(false)   string(16) "enjuto@gmail.com"   USUARIO NO ENCONTRADO
>
> USUARIO SOLICITANTE: enjuto@gmail.com
>
> USUARIO EXISTENTE BBDD:

**____________________________________________________________________________**
Seguramente,se me esté pasando algo...,pero es que no veo donde puede estar el error...,si pudierais iluminarme...me dariais la vida...

Un saludo y gracias de antemano!

Comment: amigo, no pongas imagenes, deja el codigo!, puedes agregar lo que devuelve `$this->db()->query($query)`

Comment: db() es un return de la conexion sioesi,ya esta editado el post,perdona por las imagenes,nunca habia escrito aqui jeje.

Comment: entiendo, pero `$result` que trae luego de ejecutar tu query? quiero saber para ayudarte ya que veo problemas de logica en tu login

Comment: ah vale,perdona,no te habia entendido,devuelve un correo electronico(idsUsuario),el pass,no lo he cogido,porque de momento quiero probar que me coja el correo electronico

Answer (score 0):

Primero, veo que la logica de login es que verifiques si el username y la password corresponden a un usuario de tu base de datos asi que deberia ser algo asi (ignoro como generas las password)

Luego

```
public function loguearUsuario($username, $password){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";

    $resultado = $this->db()->query($query);

    return $resultado;
}
```

Luego verificar si hay respuesta

```
$result = $usuario->loguearUsuario($username, $password);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Nombre: " . $row["nombre"];
    }
}else {
    echo "Usuario o password incorrectos";
}
```

Comment: Buenas sioesi!,encontré el error,y es que estaba comparando un objeto(que era lo de que devolvía loguearUsuario()),con un string(que era lo que llegaba del $_POST['idUsuario']),la solucion era esta

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría algo así:

```
public function loguearUsuario($idUsuario, $pass){

        $query = "SELECT idUsuario FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario = ".$idUsuario . " AND password = '" . $pass . "'";

        $resultado = $this->db()->query($query);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado );    

        if ($resultado == 0)
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
    }
```

public function loguear(){

```
$idUsuario = $_POST['idUsuario']; //es el correo electronico
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$usuario = new Usuario();
if ($usuario->loguearUsuario($idUsuario, $pass)) {
     echo "BINGO !";
}
else {
     echo "NO NO NO";
}
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Buenas chicos,encontré el error,y es que estaba comparando un objeto(que era lo de que devolvía loguearUsuario()),con un String(que era lo que llegaba del $_POST['idUsuario']),la solución era esta

```
    public function loguearUsuario($idUsuario)
{

    // $query = "SELECT idUsuario FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario = ".$idUsuario;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario = '" . $idUsuario . "'";
    $resultado = $this->db()->query($query);
    return $resultado->fetch_array(); //SOLUCION!!

}
```

De esta forma,me devuelve un array con los datos del usuario con ese id,y en el controlador de usuarios,solo tengo que jugar con las posiciones del array que me llega de loguearUsuario(),y utilizarlas a mi antojo

```
public function loguear(){

        $usuario = new Usuario();

            $idUsuario = $_POST['idUsuario']; //es el correo electronico
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];

            $usuario->setIdUsuario($idUsuario); //seteo el idUsuario
            $usuarioQueSolicitaLoguearse = $usuario->getIdUsuario(); //lo recojo
            $usuarioEnBaseDeDatos = $usuario->loguearUsuario($usuarioQueSolicitaLoguearse); //consulto a la base de datos el idUsuario introducido por el usuario

                if($usuarioQueSolicitaLoguearse == $usuarioEnBaseDeDatos[0] && $pass == $usuarioEnBaseDeDatos[1]){

                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['usuarioLogueado'] = $usuarioEnBaseDeDatos[2]; //guardo el nick
                    $_SESSION['passUsuarioLogueado'] = $usuarioEnBaseDeDatos[1]; //guardo el pass


                    // redireccciono al controlador y el metodo logueo
                    $this->redirect("Usuarios","logueo");
                }else{

                        //redireccciono al controlador y el metodo logueoNotFound
                        $this->redirect("Usuarios","logueoNotFound");
                }
    }
```

Gracias por vuestras respuestas,pero quería compartir la solución,para que no piensen que soy de lo muchos que entran aquí solo para le busquen una solución al problema,y luego no lo agradecen.

Un saludo!!